# Square root calculator breaks when asked for more precise answer

Tags: java, newtons-method

This is my code for a school assignment. I was supposed to create code that could calculate the square root of any number using Newton's method and starting guess. It was working correctly when the epsilon was 0.0001 however I was asked to make it more precise. When changed to 0.00000001 (requested by my teacher) it infinitely loops because it is repeatedly giving an answer that does is not within 0.00000001 the target number when multiplied by itself, and all further calculations yield the same result.

```
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number you are trying to find the square root of");
    Float input1 = sc.nextFloat();
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Provide a guess to start");
    Float input2 = sc2.nextFloat();
    calc(input1, input2);
    }
    static void calc(Float input1, Float input2) {
       final double epsilon = 0.00000001; 
        float sqr = (input1/input2 + input2)/2;
        do{
        sqr = (input1/input2 + input2)/2;
        input2 = sqr;
        } while (Math.abs(sqr * sqr - input1)>epsilon);
        System.out.println("The square root of " + input1 + " is " + sqr);
        
    }}
```

Comment: `float` doesn't have enough precision for that. Use `double`.

Comment: As an aside: there's no need to use `Float` here: use `float` (or, as suggested, `double`) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers only have a limited precision.

The significant concept is the *unit of least precision*, or ULP. This is the amount the number varies by if you waggle its least significant bit.

This changes depending on the number you're starting from; but for `1.0f`, the ULP is `1.1920929E-7`. (You can find this using the [`Math.ulp` method](https://ideone.com/Ajgm4L)). So, assuming you're trying to find something a better solution from something of the order 1, using `float`, you can't get within 1e-8 of it.

Use `double` instead: you still have limited precision, but the ULP is much smaller: 2.2e-16.

Comment: And for everything else, there's `BigDecimal` and tears.